# Background-image vs background

Tags: css, image, background, background-image

Im facing a weird problem which probably has a simple solution that i am completely blind to.

I want to change the background: to a background-image: but it does not seem to display the image if i do that. The code below displays no image

```
#background {
background-image: transparent url('src/assets/images/splash.jpg') 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
background-size: contain;
 opacity: 1;
```

}

meanwhile the text below displays the image.

```
#background {
background: transparent url('src/assets/images/splash.jpg') 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
background-size: contain;
opacity: 1;
```

What am i missing here...?

I would like to change it to background-image in order to simply add a gradient toning to the background

Comment: Did you check the specs? [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) accepts only images (and gradients) and [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) sets all background style properties at once

Comment: pretty strange behaviour, could you try adding a slash for the source, it might not finding the src folder.. like this: url('./src/../../../splash.jpg')

Comment: @Benji the slash did not change anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`background` is a shorthand property that takes multiple values so you can set (in your example) the `background-color`, the `background-image`, the `background-position`, the `background-repeat` and the `background-origin` in one go.

The `background-image` property only lets you set the background image (it *does* take multiple values, but all of them are background images which it renders in a stack).

Comment: Thanks! It worked if i removed the other values, so background-image: url('src/assets/images/splash.jpg'); works.